# Is it possible to exclude specific hosts from a Nagios check_command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, nagios

I've got the following configuration:

```
define host {
name                            generic-host

[...]

check_command                   check-host-alive

[...]

register                        0
}
```

*check-host-alive* is the default ping check that reports critical when there is a 100% packet loss or 5000ms round trip time.

When defining a host, I'm using this as a template. Now I need to monitor a host that blocks ICMP/Echo requests and Nagios permanently tells me that it's offline.

The host is defined like this:

```
define host {
host_name                   some.example.com
use                         generic-host
hostgroups                  my-servers
address                     127.0.0.1
}
```

Since there are multiple servers in my configuration and all of them need to be checked whether they're alive, I need to exclude this single one from the *check-host-alive* check.
Is there a way to do that?

PS: The sysadmins responsible for the server that is to be monitored will not allow ICMP/Echo request under any circumstances for reasons unknown to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add an alternative way to check for an alive host (e.g. SSH, HTTP or whatever makes sense in your environment) that overrides the definition in your template.

```
define host {
   host_name                   some.example.com
   use                         generic-host
   hostgroups                  my-servers
   address                     127.0.0.1
   check_command               ssh-check
 }
```

Of course, you must define `ssh-check` for this to work.

See https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectinheritance.html

Comment: I thought about that mere minutes after posting the question but I wanted to see if there are better ways to do it.
Thank you for the suggestion, I will try doing that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just *not* have a host check, but you can use any plugin as a host check.

In cases where `check_ping` or `check_icmp` is not an option, the next best thing is to use `check_tcp` pointed at an open port (target something stable like ssh, which is a good analog for "is the host up").

If you really can't have a host check, there's always `check_dummy`, but this will mess up the check/notification logic, resulting in a notification for every service on the host, if/when it goes down.

Comment: I will use a combination of yours and Svens suggestion but since he came first, I marked his post as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set "checks_enabled 0" for that one host.  But Sven's recommendation of an alternate check_command is probably better.

Comment: Since there are other checks done on that host, that won't be an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

`generic-host`
 is your base template and if you want to change a parameter of the Inherited values, you can overwrite the parameter with your own.